# fatal error .cubin is not in keyword=value format

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda

I'm trying to optimize a CUDA kernel by breaking it into four separate kernels.  I've prototyped all these kernels at the beginning of my code.

```
__global__ void knowles_flux__oligomers(double*, double*);
__global__ void knowles_flux__nucleus(double*, double*);
__global__ void knowles_flux__fibrils(double*, double*);
__global__ void knowles_flux__maxlength(double*, double*);
__device__ void calcFlux(double*, double*, double*);

... Code ...

__device__ void calcFlux(double* concs, double* fluxes, double* dt)
{
    knowles_flux_fibrils<<< numBlocks, numThreads >>>(fluxes, concs);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    knowles_flux_oligomers<<< 1, nc-1 >>>(fluxes, concs);
    knowles_flux_nucleus<<< 1, 1 >>>(fluxes, concs);
    knowles_flux_maxlength<<< 1, 1 >>>(fluxes, concs);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
__global__ void knowles_flux_oligomers(double *fluxes, double *conc)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + 1;
    fluxes[idx] = 0;
}
__global__ void knowles_flux_nucleus(double *fluxes, double *conc)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + nc - 1;
    double frag_term = 0;
    for (int s = idx+1; s < (maxlength); s++)
    {
        frag_term += conc[s];
    }
    fluxes[idx] = (kn)*pow(conc[0],(nc)) + 2*(km)*frag_term - 2*(ka)*conc[idx]*conc[0];
}
__global__ void knowles_flux_fibrils(double *fluxes, double *conc)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    double frag_term = 0;
    for (int s = idx+1; s < (maxlength); s++)
    {
        frag_term += conc[s];
    }
    fluxes[idx] = -(km)*(idx)*conc[idx] + 2*(km)*frag_term - 2*(ka)*conc[idx]*conc[0] + 2*(ka)*conc[idx-1]*conc[0];
}
__global__ void knowles_flux_maxlength(double *fluxes, double *conc)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + maxlength - 1;
    fluxes[idx] = -km*(idx)*conc[idx]+2*(ka)*conc[idx-1]*conc[0];
}
```

Leading to the error "fatbinary : fatal error : 'Multiple Flux Kernel).sm_35.cubin'is not in 'keyword=value' format" where the 'Multiple Flux Kernel)' part is the trailing end of the source file I try to compile.

Maybe my google-fu is weak, but I'm not coming up with anything for this kind of error.

Comment: Apart from the error, you're not optimizing but adding up the burden of initiating and scheduling dynamic kernel calls for every GPU thread, which can simply be resolved by `__device__` functions. Plus your parent function doesn't do anything substantial. You don't have to use dynamic parallelism here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem had nothing to do with the code.  The error actually did have to do with the filename of the source file I was trying to compile.  The filename originally was "GPU RKF45 (Variable Step Size, Multiple Flux Kernel).cu".  The comma in the filename seemed to cause the problem.  Getting rid of that let it compile.